# Setting up eclipse Helios to run Blackberry applications

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I have downloaded eclipse Helios with blackberry plugin,now i need to run a sample app in simulator ,what are the steps to import a existing blackberry app into eclipse helios and run ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the project to the eclipse, then compile and run. new - project - blakberry project -create project from existing source -browse and add your codes.  if you want to import samples, then import - import blackberry samples.

Comment: i am not able to see blackberry project ,eventhough i have the plugin

Comment: on project - blackberry is available ?   http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4014/knowledge-sharing-center-for-blackberry-android-and-java